# mod_wsgi error with Django: Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm running Django 2.0.4 with mod_wsgi 4.5.20.

I'm getting an error when I try to deploy a site to our dev environment at `/parature`. What's weird is that the site deployed at the root of the `VirtualHost` is responding as normal:

```
[Tue Apr 10 13:34:08.998704 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 65245] [client xx.yy.zz:65390] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'parature-develop-https': /var/django/html/parature-develop/config/wsgi.py
```

I can run the site via `runserver` with the `virtualenv` activated. It shouldn't be timing out, as I'm just trying to bring up the Django admin site.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On

  ServerName wrds-pub1-dev.example.com
  ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/errorlog/%Y/%Y-%m-wrds-pub1-dev-error.log"
  LogLevel info

  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

  # The site I'm adding, which isn't working
  WSGIDaemonProcess parature-develop-https python-home=/var/django/virtualenvs/parature-develop request-timeout=600
  WSGIProcessGroup parature-develop-https
  WSGIScriptAlias /parature /var/django/html/parature-develop/config/wsgi.py process-group=parature-develop-https
  <Directory /var/django/html/parature-develop/config>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /parature/static/ /var/django/html/parature-develop/static/
  <Directory /var/django/html/parature-develop/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # The site which has been and continues to work
  WSGIDaemonProcess django-wrds-dev-https python-home=/var/django/virtualenvs/django-wrds-dev request-timeout=600
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/html/django-wrds-dev/config/wsgi.py process-group=django-wrds-dev-https
  <Directory /var/django/html/django-wrds-dev/config>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /static/ /var/django/html/django-wrds-dev/static/
  <Directory /var/django/html/django-wrds-dev/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /media/ /var/media/wrds-www/
  <Directory /var/media/wrds-www>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but can't see it. I've got a similar configuration in another `VirtualHost` with multiple Django projects under the same domain, and that is working fine, as long as the root site comes last.

The `wsgi.py` is almost exactly the same as the site that is working as well:

```
import os, sys, logging
from socket import gethostname
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Since this powers Apache, let's route Python errors to the Apache
# log rather than STDOUT, where they'll never be seen.
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

# Figure out where we're at, and add the parent to the path
sys.path.append(os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2]))

# wrds-pub1-dev server
if 'wrds-pub1-dev' in gethostname():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
# wrds-pub* production servers.
elif 'wrds-pub' in gethostname():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
# else use dev settings.
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - our dev server (since there's never a good time for a rebuild) is our only non-Ansiblized server, and still running `mod_wsgi` built against Python 3.5. The `virtualenv` was built against Python 3.6.

I rebuilt the `virtualenv` against Python 3.5, and everything works. Hopefully this saves someone hair-pulling in the future!

Comment: Hi there, I'm in a similar situation right now. I've installed mod_wsgi using `pip install mod_wsgi` in my virtualenv, there by ensuring that both use the same python version. 

yet my requests are getting timed out and I get an error exactly like you were getting.

Comment: Are you sure that Apache is pointing to the `mod_wsgi.so` that gets built inside the virtualenv of your project? Or that you've moved the compiled `.so` file somewhere central?